# How to divide a very large number(10^100), when number is stored as single digits in array

Tags: c

Say there is a very large number, 100 digits which is stored in an array. Now i want to divide this number by another number(say 2) , Can anyone suggest how to do it?

Comment: On the off chance that this is a question about a practical problem, note that 100 digits is not _that_ large. A bignum system on a modern computer can easily handle numbers an order of magnitude larger. So one practical solution is to use existing libraries such as [GMP](https://gmplib.org/).

Comment: @svk A question how to implement this yourself is perfectly fine, while a question about where a bignum library can be found is off-topic for SO.

Comment: Suppose you had a very large number, a *two digit* number stored in an array. And you wanted to divide it by two. How would you do it?  If you can solve it for two, you can solve it for 1000000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do it exactly as you would do that on paper. For small divisors (as 2) this is an O(d) algorithm (where d is the number of digits) and it is impossible to find anything asymptotically better since you need to check each digit at least once.